# groovy (java): exec() do not detach from process (Intellij IDEA vs Maven+TestNG)

Tags: maven-2, exec, testng, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I have Groovy Maven2 test project with TestNG and Surefire plugin enabled.

I want to launch external process (*.cmd file which start some *.exe file) in last test method, finish my tests and left process running after tests.

I tried the following codes to do it:

**1 attempt**

```
def builder = new ProcessBuilder('cmd','/c <name>.cmd')
builder.directory( ( new File( <path_to_working_directory> ) ) )
builder.start()
```

**2 attempt** (with and without start cmd option)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /c start <name>.cmd", null , ( new File( <path_to_working_directory> ) ) )
```

**3 attempt**

```
( new AntBuilder() ).exec(
    dir: "<path_to_working_directory>",
    executable: "<name>.cmd"
)
```

Where .cmd is:

```
set path=<path_to_execFile>;%path%
start <execFileName>.exe
```

When I launch each of these codes from Intellij IDEA via 'Run' functionality (Alt+Shift+F10) codes execute successfully, process started and run after test finishes.

When I launch each of these codes both from Intellij IDEA Maven task, clean Maven installation (and even Maven task from Jenkins) process started successfully but test remains running. I need to kill it manually. When I kill test process (Maven process) manually my launched external process continue to work as I expect.

This hung test process is my headache for the moment.

I looked through a lot of materials but didn't find any root cause, fix and even workaround for this issue. I see that all my attempts (perhaps, except of AntBuilder()) create deattached processes. I suppose that this can be connected with JVM settings. But I coudnl't find to which one.

Also, I tried

```
"full command to run my cmd".execute()
```

but it didn't help me too.

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, I do not see any answers for my issue here. But I have some updates.

I found that I can use PsExec tool instead of direct cmd calling:

```
def builder = new ProcessBuilder( 'psexec', 'cmd', '/c', '<name>.cmd' )
builder.directory( ( new File( <path_to_working_directory> ) ) )
builder.start()
```

And this code works fine when I launch it from clean Maven only (not from Jenkins): process started, Maven task completes successfully, the process continues to run.

But during execute this code as part of some Maven2 Jenkins task I faced to issue again: psexec started but Jenkins task is running and my process does not started before I terminate Jenkins task manually.

To avoid this issue I created simple additional Groovy service script I launch in [listen mode](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+CLI) (and [Writing a TCP Server](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/sockets.html)) on target machine manually during initial machine preparation. This script is running on machine always.

I send to this listener name of command file to execute from my test I launch from Jenkins and it executes all cmds successfully: processes start, Jenkins task completes successfully, processes continue to run. I use processbuilder inside this listener.

For name sending I use [simple socket (Writing a TCP Client)](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/sockets.html)

Also, I found [how to detach child from process tree on win32?](https://www.java.net//forum/topic/general-programming-help/how-detach-child-process-tree-win32). But for me system my way looks more Groovy I think.