# Maven: setup Maven to use javaw instead of java (running from Jenkins)

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, javaw

I need to setup Maven (clean and as Jenkins task) to use javaw instead of java. I do not find such setup option. I see only path to jre.

Could you please help me with the setup?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Only way I found to use javaw instead of java for Jenkins task is renaming javaw->java =( I know how its stupied. So, I do not use it. But for my main task it didn't help. Note: you can setup to use javaw in Jenkins agent in very simple way - in jenkins agent xml properties file on each slave. But tasks will launch with java anyway.

Comment: Why you need to do it?

Comment: @Michael because of [detach child process during launch from Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045593/groovy-java-exec-do-not-detach-from-process-intellij-idea-vs-maventestng)

Comment: You might try tweaking your mvn.bat(for windows) or mvn script file in bin directory of your maven installation. These files are written in such a way assuming you have your JAVA_HOME as an environment variable. I have not done this before. But you could try. Let us know how it works. Again changing this would affect other applications using this maven installation. So you might have to use a separate installation just for yout jenkins job that is going to use this.